# RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless issues

Tags: wireless, 14.10, realtek

I have a ThinkPad T450s that drop out of a wifi connexion after few seconds.
Sometimes, I can't even connect to the network. I know it must be a driver issue, but the stuff I found online is about other Realtek drivers, I would appreciate if someone could give me some direction.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10
The wireless driver is "RTL8192EE"
Driver version : "3.16.0-33-generic"

Let me know if you want the output of come commands...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the driver you compiled is *rtl8192ee*, please confirm in the terminal command:

```
lsmod
```

I suggest you try a driver parameter. Again, from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8192ee swenc=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ee.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if stability is improved.

Comment: It looks like your command is not complete

Comment: Indeed, @Jeremy31 Good catch. Edited.

Comment: Nope, after a lsmod, I found "rtl8192ee"

Comment: Is it something you compiled? It is included in 14.10: `/lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko`

Comment: Yes I compiled a backport driver, was one of the things I tried. I booted on a live version of 14.10 and I can confirm that r8192ee is the native on. What do you suggest ?

Comment: By any chance, are _both_ loaded?

Comment: It not "more or less" stable since I compiled it, how could I validate that ? (my lsmod only talks about rtl8192ee, not the native one)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22680/discussion-between-chili555-and-pascal-boutin).

Comment: Do not forget to compile AES in kernel, otherwise it will fail to use encryption. `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES, CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_TI, CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_X86_64`

Comment: @puchu It is not necessary to recompile the kernel to get AES to work in any recent Ubuntu version.